# Dossier Reporting for Rails: Why am I getting a missing template error when clicking CSV link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, ruby-on-rails-4, report, reporting

I am using [Dossier gem](https://github.com/tma1/dossier) and most of my reports work except the following report.  Not sure what I am missing here.

reports/cases_by_user_report.rb:

```
  class CasesByUserReport < Dossier::Report

  def sql
    Case.joins(:case_contacts => :contact).where("cases.firm_id = :firm_id 
      AND role IN ('Attorney', 'Staff')
      AND user_account_id IN :user_contact_id
      AND cases.status IN :status"
      ).select("last_name, first_name, case_number, name, subtype, status"
      ).uniq.to_sql
  end

  def firm_id
      options[:firm_id]
  end

  def user_contact_id
    User.find(options[:user_contact_id])
  end

  def status
    options[:status]
  end
end
```

ReportController#cases_by_user_report:

```
def cases_by_user_report
    @user_all_id_array = []
    @firm.contacts.where("type IN ('Attorney', 'Staff')").each do |contact| 
      if User.exists?(contact.user_account_id)
        @user_all_id_array << contact.user_account_id 
      end
    end 
    @user_ = params[:contact] && params[:contact][:contact_id] != '' ? params[:contact][:contact_id].split(",").map(&:to_i) : @user_all_id_array.uniq
    @selected_user = params[:contact][:contact_id] if params[:contact]
    @statuses = params[:status] ? params[:status] : Case::STATUS
    @cases_by_user_report = CasesByUserReport.new(firm_id: @firm.id, user_contact_id: @user_, status: @statuses)
  end
```

views/reports/cases_by_user_report.html.erb:

```
<%= form_tag reports_cases_by_user_path, method: :get do %>
<div class="case-header">
    <div class="case-title">
          <div style="font-size: 24px;">
                <strong>Cases by User</strong><br>
          </div>
            <div id="case-buttons">
              <ul>
                    <li><%= submit_tag "RUN REPORT", name: nil, :class => 'run-report' %></li>
              </ul>
          </div>
    </div>
    <!-- .collect {|contact| contact.name }) -->
        <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0; margin-top: 10px;">
              <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                        User<br>
                            <%= collection_select :contact, :contact_id, @firm.users.joins(:contacts).where("type IN ('Attorney', 'Staff')").uniq, :id, :name, :include_blank => true, :class => 'table-input', :selected => @selected_user %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
                        Status<br>
                          <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(Case::STATUS), multiple: true, :class => 'table-input', :placeholder => 'All Statuses' %>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-6">
                        </div>
              </div>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="incase-tabs-gap"></div>
<% end %>
<div style="margin-top: 72px;">
<div class="span6">
  <%= render template: 'dossier/reports/show', locals: {report: @cases_by_user_report.run} %>
</div>
```

EDIT:
Error I am receiving:

```
Missing template reports/cases_by_user_report, application/cases_by_user_report with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:csv], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :haml, :jbuilder]}
```

EDIT 2:
One difference I noticed, for the successful reports, this line comes up in my console/logs:

```
Processing by Dossier::ReportsController#show as CSV
```

Whereas for the reports in error, I get the following:

```
Processing by ReportsController#cases_by_user_report as CSV
```

Comment: try to `respond` block in controller

Comment: I don't have that in any of the other actions, not sure why this one would need it.

Comment: did you get `@cases_by_user_report` in view?

Comment: What do you mean?  I am running it by @cases_by_user_report.run

Comment: Does anybody know what's going on?  Can anyone point me to something?